# Keep having to start ElasticSearch on Ubuntu start up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, elasticsearch, faraday

I am using the latest Ubuntu build 15.10 and have gone through the install of ElasticSearch here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-service.html

However, even after executing the command that adds the service to the start up process.

```
sudo update-rc.d elasticsearch defaults 95 10
sudo /etc/init.d/elasticsearch start
```

Rebooting the computer, then going to localhost:9200 gives a 404.

And every single morning I run the `sudo /etc/init.d/elasticsearch start`, then the `sudo update-rc.d elasticsearch defaults 95 10` in hopes that tomorrow will be a different day, to find my machine in the exact same state as yesterday.

On a side note, my machine at work uses the same version of Ubuntu and the steps described above worked on the first try.

If anyone has overcome this issue, your insight would be very appreciated!

Thanks you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu, since version 15.04, is [using `systemd` by default](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers) instead of the older `upstart` for handling services and init scripts. I think you need to initialize elasticsearch differently, as [described in the ES docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-service.html#using-systemd).

Something like:

```
sudo /bin/systemctl daemon-reload
sudo /bin/systemctl enable elasticsearch.service
sudo /bin/systemctl start elasticsearch.service
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! I'm so sorry for the long wait, you had answered so fast! I've been working like a maniac and haven't even restarted the computer until now, and it works wonderfully thank you!